# Touchscreen stopped working

Tags: touchscreen

I have Ubuntu 12.10 running with a touchscreen from iiyama (prolite T1531SR) which operates over a VGA plug over an adapter into a HDMI port and a separate USB port to operate the touch screen.

When I run lsusb I can still find the screen, however not with a xinput --list command.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It would be nice if you could remove your answer from the question and add it as an answer instead. You can then accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

In `/etc/modules.conf` I had to add

```
usbtouchscreen
```