# Touchscreen unresponsive after reboot

Tags: power-management, touchscreen, 18.10

Sometime in the last 3 days, I rebooted my laptop and found my touchscreen was no longer working. I Don't think the kernel has been updated, which means there's either a hardware problem, a recent update, or I screwed something up.

I've tried:

> $ xinput enable "ELAN0732:00 04F3:2719"

but no luck. My power settings are showing the touchscreen as having 0% power. Anyone have any ideas?

Update: Now seeing this in `dmesg`:

> [   20.842008] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0732:00: failed to reset device.

Tried adding `blacklist i2c-hid` to my `modprobe.d/blacklist` and rebooting, but no luck yet.

Comment: These links may be of help: [Touchscreen stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401558/touchscreen-stopped-working) and [touch screen not working](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325676)

Comment: Super unhelpful here, but I do have my [kernel patched](https://hackido.com/blog/2018/11/01/patch-ubuntu-kernel.html). Restarting did not solve my problem at any point, but I shut down and booted up and for some reason that restored my touchscreen. <shrug>